# Change Icon Color Tab Bar Controller-SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am working in Xcode 6 with SWIFT and have been able to successfully change the color of the text on my tab bar controller, but I cannot get the color to change on the icons themselves. My code below in the AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 239/255, green: 64/255, blue: 54/255, alpha: 1.0)], forState: .Selected)
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: .Normal)
```

I have a separate class for the navigation controller to change text and color.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `image` on the tab bar item to a `UIImage` with `renderingMode = UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate`

Then you can set the `tintColor` on the  `UITabBar` to change the color of the icons and the text simultaneously. You should still be able to override 
that for the text with the appearance selectors you have created though.

If I recall, `UITabBar` should set the `renderingMode` automatically, so try just setting the `tintColor` first.

Comment: I set the images through the story board, not through code. Is there a way I can set [renderingMode = UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate] in App delegate?

Comment: You will need to create your tab bar items programmatically to set the `renderingMode`. If I remember correctly, the tab bar should default to the correct `renderingMode` though. Have you tried just setting the `tintColor`?

Comment: Yeah I can set the barTintColor (The actual bar). but when I try to do it for the UITabItem not the UITab, it says it does not possess those properties. I guess I will have to set them through the code instead of storeyboard.

Comment: Not the `barTintColor` the `UITabBar` itself should ALSO have a `tintColor`. That should be what you are looking for. It should be down at the bottom of the attributes inspector on the storyboard. Underneath the `background` color.